# Check if multiple records already exits and then insert new records MySql

Tags: mysql

**Sorry if my question is inappropriate but I need the answer for one of my project**

Actually, I want to insert multiple records from `table1` to `table2` of MySql. But before inserting records in `table2`, I need to check if any record already exists in `table2`, and If any single record exists then skip that record and insert the remaining ones.

For Example: I want to insert record 101 & 102 in `table2` from `table1` but if record 101 already exists in table2 then skip 101 and insert 102.

This is my code to insert record from `table1` to `table2`

```
INSERT INTO table2 (owner_id, month,date,medium, monthly_rent, tax_deduction, final_payment)

SELECT id, 'sep2020','2020/10/05',medium, monthly_rent, tax_deduction, final_payment
 FROM table1

WHERE table1.id =('100','101')
```

Comment: If you are using MySQL, please don't tag other RDBMS (such as [tag:sql-server]).

Comment: Do you have any indexes on table2?

Comment: indexes mean ?? @P.Salmon Sorry I am not that expert

Comment: Do you have a primary or unique key on id?

Comment: Yes ID is unique and primary in both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a primary key on id you could use INSERT IGNORE..https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html which will throw a warning if a duplicate key is detected and won't add a new row. for example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT, VAL INT);
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT PRIMARY KEY,VAL INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (101,10),(102,20),(103,30);

INSERT IGNORE INTO T1 
 SELECT ID,VAL
FROM T;

UPDATE T SET VAL = 50 WHERE ID = 101;

INSERT IGNORE INTO T1 
 SELECT ID,VAL
FROM T;



mysql> SELECT * FROM T;
+------+------+
| ID   | VAL  |
+------+------+
|  101 |   50 |
|  102 |   20 |
|  103 |   30 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM T1;
+-----+------+
| ID  | VAL  |
+-----+------+
| 101 |   10 |
| 102 |   20 |
| 103 |   30 |
+-----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It seems that you want to add a row to table2 every time an new row is added to table1 so it may be worth considering a trigger to do the job. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html